# Parsing XML using R is returning empty character strings

Tags: xml, r, types, xml-parsing

I'm trying to follow [this guide](http://giventhedata.blogspot.com/2012/06/r-and-web-for-beginners-part-ii-xml-in.html#comment-form). I can print my XML as so:

```
> print(deps[1:2])
$deployment
<deployment id="0">
 <deploy t="0" u="2"/>
 <deploy t="1" u="2"/>
 <deploy t="2" u="2"/>
 <deploy t="3" u="2"/>
 <deploy t="4" u="5"/>
 <deploy t="5" u="2"/>
 <metric name="makespan" value="23"/>
 <rmetric name="total_cpu_cycles" value="16340"/>
</deployment>

$deployment
<deployment id="1">
 <deploy t="0" u="2"/>
 <deploy t="1" u="2"/>
 <deploy t="2" u="2"/>
 <deploy t="3" u="2"/>
 <deploy t="4" u="5"/>
 <deploy t="5" u="2"/>
 <metric name="makespan" value="23"/>
 <rmetric name="total_cpu_cycles" value="16350"/>
</deployment>

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeList"
```

What I would like is a matrix where each row is a deployment and there are two columns ('makespan', 'total_cpu_cycles').

When I get to this step I start seeing problems:

```
> depcat = xmlSApply(deps, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
> depcat[1,1]
[[1]]
character(0)
> str(depcat[1,1])
List of 1
 $ : chr(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm silly. There's no xmlValue because each item looks like this:  `<deploy t="0" u="2"/>` instead of this `<deploy t="0" u="2">some value</deploy>`